# Counting the Number of Combinations of Unique Values Per ID

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, data-manipulation

```
id = sample.int(50,1000, replace = TRUE)
years <- c("2010", "2011", "2013", "2014", "2015")
year<- sample(years, 1000, prob=c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2, 0.2), replace = TRUE)
my_data =  data.frame(id, year)
my_data <- my_data[order(id),]
```

For example, patient # 1 visited the hospital twice in 2010, once in 2011, no times in 2012 ... patient # 2 visited the hospital no times in 2010, 5 times in 2011, 3 times in 2012, etc.

For this dataset, I want to find out the number of the number of times each combination of "years" appears (not including duplicates). For example - since there are 5 possible years, there will be 2^5 = 32 possible combinations :

```
# sample output of the final result
                    combinations frequency
                           2010        11
                           2011         9
                           2012         5
                           2013         1
                           2014        19
                           2015        11
                      2011,2012         9
               2011, 2012, 2013         5
                     2013, 2015         1
  2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015        19
```

This would be the equivalent of finding out:

- How many patients visited the hospital only in 2010?
- How many patients visited the hospital in 2010 and 2013?
- etc.

I tried to find a way to do this different ways:

```
# Method 1: Did not work
library(data.table)
final = setDT(my_data)[,list(Count=.N) ,names(my_data)]

# Method 2: Did not work

final =  = aggregate(.~year,rev(aggregate(.~id,my_data,paste0,collapse = ",")),length) 

# Method 3: Not sure if this is correct? There are 50 rows (instead of 32) and all frequency counts are 1?

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df = my_data %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(years = str_c(year, collapse=",")) %>% 
    count(years)
```

**My Question:** Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R:

```r
table(tapply(my_data$year, my_data$id, 
             function(x) paste(sort(unique(x)), collapse=',')))
```

Comment: @  Robert Hacken: Thank you so much! This is such an elegant answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to first get the combinations of years for each patient and then count them

```
# with data.table
setDT(my_data)
my_data_agg<-my_data[,.(combinations=paste(sort(unique(year)), collapse=",")), by=.(id)]
my_data_agg[,.N, by=.(combinations)]
```

Comment: @ Ivana: Thank you so much for your answer! I think in your code, (2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015) is being considered different when compared to (2010,2011,2012, 2013,2015,2014). Is there a way to fix this? Thank you so much!

Comment: It is possible. To solve add `sort()` around `unique()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>%
  group_by(id, year) %>%
  summarise(frequency = n()) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(combinations = str_c(year, collapse=",")) %>% 
  count(combinations)
```

Output:

```
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  combinations                 n
  <chr>                    <int>
1 2010,2011,2013,2014,2015    49
2 2010,2011,2013,2015          1
```

This means that there is one patient, which does not went to the hospital in 2014. And it seems that all patient do not went to the hospital in 2012.

By using this code, we can check which patient did not went to the hospital in 2014:

```
my_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!all(2014 %in% year)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  distinct(id) %>%
  pull(id)
```

Output:

```
[1] 12
```

So patient 12 did not went to hospital in 2014.

Comment: thank you so much for this answer! I wonder if the "show_query()" command  can be applied to the first code and automatically convert the dplyr into SQL code?

Comment: I replaced the "summarise" line with this and it worked! summarise(combinations = str_flatten(year , ",")) %>%